# SELECT * FROM dblist WHERE date?

Tags: php, mysql, date, select

I have my date from my date input : 20-10-2016

```
echo "<form method='post' action='rapor.php'>";
echo "<input type='date' name='pickdate' value=".date("Y-m-d")."> <input type='submit' value='Git'>";
echo "</form>";

$pickeddate = strtr($_POST['pickdate'], '/', '-');
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($pickeddate));
```

And result of this : 2016-10-20

So far so good..

I need to show only rows date i have picked.

```
+------+-------------+---------------------+
| name |  mail       | dateandtime         |
+------+-------------+---------------------+
| AAA  |   a@a.com   | 2016-04-20 06:44:19 |
| BDC  |   b@c.com   | 2016-10-21 06:44:19 |
| CDD  |   c@d.com   | 2016-04-10 06:44:19 |
| EED  |   e@d.com   | 2016-10-20 06:44:19 |
| SAS  |   a@s.com   | 2016-04-10 06:44:19 |
+------+-------------+---------------------+
```

thats my result code but....

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM dblist WHERE ('$pickeddate%')  ');
```

why not working?

Comment: Check whether the where clause is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
$newdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($pickeddate)); 
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM dblist WHERE dateandtime LIKE  "'.$newdate.'%"  ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your field name?

Try this

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM dblist WHERE dateandtime LIKE ('$pickeddate%')  ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$pickeddate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['pickdate']));
SELECT * FROM dblist WHERE date(dateandtime) LIKE '$pickeddate%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify column name to do condition with as,

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM dblist WHERE dateandtime LIKE  "'.$pickeddate.'%"  ');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try below query for your expected result

```
$newdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($pickeddate)); 
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM dblist WHERE DATE(dateandtime) = "'.$newdate.'"');
```

This will be compare exact date.